# Indexing an array in C returns a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

I am working on a project that requires me to read user inputs as pairs of integers and then store them in an array. So, I have created a function that does this. However, I for some reason get a segmentation fault everytime the last input is entered.  Here is my code:

```
int userInput(int *arrayPtr){

    int numberPairs, i, numberElements;
    printf("%d", sizeof(int));

    printf("How many pairs of integers? ");
    scanf("%d", &numberPairs);
    numberElements = numberPairs*2;
    arrayPtr = malloc((numberElements*sizeof(int)) + 64);

    for(i = 0; i < numberElements; i+=2){
        int first,second;
        printf("\nEnter pair: ");
        printf("Before scanf");
        scanf("%d %d", &first, &second);
        printf("%d", first);
        arrayPtr[i] = first;
        arrayPtr[i+1] = second;
    }   
    printf("%d", numberPairs);

    return numberPairs;
}
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
int main(){
    int *arrayPtr, numberPairs;
    numberPairs = userInput(arrayPtr);
    multiplyPairs(arrayPtr, numberPairs);
    free(arrayPtr);
}
```

At the moment, I am mainly trying to make the for loop execute in its entirety, but for some reason it always seg faults on the last iteration.  For example, if my input for the pairs was 1 2, 3 4, 5 6, my ouput would be 1 3 and then a seg fault (this output is referring to the print statement in the for loop).  I have spent a few hours trying to debug this code as well as having other students look at it, and I can not figure out what is wrong.  If you could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

UPDATE: I copied and pasted the code into a new file and it works as intended.  Thank you to everyone who told me about other elements of my code that were wrong.

Comment: Are you passing an `int *` into this function and then expecting it to point to the array allocated by this function? `arrayPtr = ...` completely decouples `arrayPtr` from whatever the caller passed.

Comment: I am not passing in any information with the array pointer.  I just declare it in my main function so that it has the proper scope. Because I use the same arrayPtr as parameters for other functions.

Comment: Show how you call the function. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Excuse my harsh remark, but if the code is slack re output formatting where numbers are jammed up to strings without space or newline, the rest of the code is likely to be just as sloppy. Please put `newline`s at the end of print statements, not before. One example is the output of an `int` in the last iteration of the loop which runs right into the  `int` printed afterwards. How do you know which digits belong to which `int`?

Comment: I can't replicate your segfault: https://ideone.com/SatQ1G Are you really running exactly what you posted here?

Comment: Exactly which line segfaults? If you define first and secon outside the loop does it still seg fault?

Comment: Why is this `arrayPtr` a parameter at all? Your `userInput` function completely ignores and discards it; the array allocated in this function will not be visible to any other functions. If you do `userInput(ptr); otherThing(ptr);`, the call to `otherThing` won't see the work of `userInput`.

Comment: Did you try a debugger? Debugger == your friend.

Comment: I notice that you do not free the array that you malloc. Since you do not pass it back, (with a `**` in the argument, you will have memory leakage which will eventually cause problems.

Comment: @user234461.  I am running exactly what is shown here.  I compile it using the line gcc -ansi -pedantic lab4p1.c -o lab4p1.

Comment: @sabbahillel I am not sure which line seg faults exactly, but the program does not output the print statement before the last iteration of the array index.  So it would have to be with the scanf.

Comment: @user2357112 ArrayPtr is a parameter because I am actively changing what the elements of it are.  I then pass it into another function later on in the main.

Comment: @sabbahillel. If I free the arrayPtr in that function then I won't be able to use it in the other function call in the main.

Comment: @BrandonMinner: "I am actively changing what the elements of it are" - Yeah, that's not happening. `userInput` throws that parameter away. The `arrayPtr` in `main` is still garbage when it's passed to `multiplyPairs`. (In fact, even passing that pointer to `userInput` was undefined behavior.)

Comment: @user2357112 So does that mean I need to pass the pointer into the function as a double pointer?

Comment: @BrandonMinner: Using an `int **` would address the problem.

Comment: you should be compiling with all warnings enable, not just -pedantic.  Suggest: `gcc -ggnu -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99 lab4pl.c -o lab4pl o -I.`   followed by:  `gcc -ggnu lab4pl.o -o lab4pl`

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  when calling any of the `scanf()` faimily of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when a sub function wants to change the contents of a pointer in the caller function, the parameter must be passed similar to: `subFunc( &arrayPtr); `  and the sub function must have a signature similar to: `subFunc( char **arrayPtr )`  Then any changing of the pointer in the caller would be done similar to: `*arrayPtr = malloc( ... );`  Which should be followed by: `if( NULL == *arrayPtr ) {//handle error}`

Comment: In the posted code, this line: `numberPairs = userInput(arrayPtr);*/` has an extraneous, trailing  `*/`.  hopefully, that is just a copy/paste error.

Comment: When you malloc() and put the pointer created into arrayPTR, you are creating a locla variable that is thrown away. For example consider `myadd(int n) { printf("%d\n", n); n++; printf("%d\n", n);}` and call myadd with n=1 and printf n after leaving `myadd()`. You will see that n is changed from 1 to 2 inside `myadd()` and is back to 1 after it gets back to the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
int userInput(int **arrayPtr){

    int numberPairs, i, numberElements;
    printf("%d", sizeof(int));

    printf("How many pairs of integers? ");
    scanf("%d", &numberPairs);
    numberElements = numberPairs*2;
    *arrayPtr = malloc((numberElements*sizeof(int)) + 64);

    for(i = 0; i < numberElements; i+=2){
        int first,second;
        printf("\nEnter pair: ");
        printf("Before scanf");
        scanf("%d %d", &first, &second);
        printf("%d", first);
        (*arrayPtr)[i] = first;
        (*arrayPtr)[i+1] = second;
    }   
    printf("%d", numberPairs);

    return numberPairs;
}


int main(){
    int *arrayPtr, numberPairs;
    numberPairs = userInput(&arrayPtr);
    multiplyPairs(arrayPtr, numberPairs);
    free(arrayPtr);
}
```

**Explanation using a very simple example**

You want to write a function that mutiplies the first with it's second argument and stores the value in the third agrument.

So you try this:

```
void Multiply(int a, int b, int r)
{
  r = a * b;
}

int main(){
    int result = 0;
    Multiply(3, 4, result);
    printf ("result = %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

And you expect the output is `result = 12`. But you get `result = 0`. The reason is that when a function parameter is modified, the function argument of the caller won't be modified because the parameters are passed by value (it's like that in C and in most other programming languages). BTW what should happen if you dont pass a variable as 3rd argument but a constant: for example `Multiply(3, 4, 5);` ?

If you want your function to modify an argument, you have to pass a *pointer* to the argument to the fonction and modify the pointed value in the function:

Following example shows what to do:

```
void Multiply(int a, int b, int *r)
{
 // r points to the variable passed as third argument
  *r = a * b;
}

int main(){
    int result = 0;

    // here we pass the pointer to result
    Multiply(3, 4, &result);

    printf ("result = %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```